# Change python version in script apache

Tags: python, apache

im have next script

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

import sys
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return sys.version

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and im have 2 version python 2.7 and 3.5

this sctipt return 2.7.9 (default, Apr 2 2015, 15:37:21) [GCC 4.9.2]
How i can change version on 3.5?

Comment: Run the flask script with python3 instead of python. Which OS are you using? On Ubuntu try `python3 flask_script.py` instead of `python flask_script.py`.

Comment: im use browser for run

Comment: Yes, you view the app in your browser, but you start the script from terminal right? If not, how are you running the script?

Comment: @downshift The [tag:apache] tag means that the OP's probably using WSGI or sth similar.

Comment: ok thanks @hjpotter92